# measuring performance golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, appstats

I am learning how to make a website on App Engine using Golang. I want a way to do performance profiling. I am trying to use [appstats](https://godoc.org/github.com/mjibson/appstats). However there are two issues

- Is there a work around to avoid using strict function structure

> func(appengine.Context, http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)

- Second, I am using httprouter for mapping multiple pages. How to use appstats with httprouter? Is there better alternative than appstats?

  ```
  r := httprouter.New()
  http.Handle("/", r)

  r.GET("/", HomePage)
  //Signup routes
  r.GET("/form/signup", GoToSignupPage)
  ```

Comment: Not sure about appstats, but you could use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/ - more info: https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: How to use that with Google App engine. It is talking about if you are running your http server?

Comment: You'll find that **many** (if not most) app engine related functions will require a `Context`.